# pgfplots memory error due to specific xmax limit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am facing a problem with setting the limits of my plot in pgfplots. The following script (from an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439436/create-one-linear-line-plots-from-each-row-of-data-in-table) )

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XMax}{1.1e-3} %changing this to 1.05e-3 gives error
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XMin}{0.95e-3}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=\XMin,
  xmax=\XMax
]
\pgfplotstableread{
x y dydx
0.96e-3 2 1
0.98e-3 1 -1
0.99e-3 3 0.5
}\mydata
% get number of rows in table
% subtract 1 because row indexing starts at zero
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\AxRange}{\XMax-\XMin}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\NumRows}{ % loop over rows

  % extract the data from the table
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{x}\of\mydata
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{y}\of\mydata
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{dydx}\of\mydata
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DYDX}{\pgfplotsretval}

  % calculate start and end of domain for line
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DomainStart}{\X-\AxRange*0.1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DomainEnd}{\X+\AxRange*0.1}

  % plot
  \addplot +[domain=\DomainStart:\DomainEnd,mark=none,thick,samples=2] {\Y + \DYDX * (x-\X)};
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

creates the following figure.

[image: Plot from the script]

But changing the value of Xmax to 1.05e-3 gives the following error.

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} into your preamble.
 on input line 4.

Runaway definition?
->
./a.tex:40: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\pgfplotsapplistXXpushback@smallbufoverfl ...toka 
                                                  \the \t@pgfplots@tokb \the...
l.40 }

./a.tex:40:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /Users/manav/Desktop/.texpadtmp/a.log.
```

Why would the output be so sensitive to the xmax limit? Is there anything that can be done to force this limit without running into the error?

Answer (score 1):

It happens that one runs into such problems with `pgf`, as the numerical capabilities are a bit limited. Just like in [Why tikz fail at computation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439127/why-tikz-fail-at-computation/439132#439132), it seems that using `\fpeval` from the `xfp` package to do the calculations works here as well. I used that also to calculate the y-values of the endpoints of the lines, and used `\addplot coordinates` to plot the lines. This works with a smaller range as well, here with `xmax=1.0e-3`.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%
%% the following only for example
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
% the filecontents environment writes its content to the specified file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y dydx
0.96e-3 2 1
0.98e-3 1 -1
0.99e-3 3 0.5
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\mydata
% get number of rows in table
% subtract 1 because row indexing starts at zero
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0.95e-3,
  xmax=1.0e-3,
  samples=2
]

\edef\AxRange{\fpeval{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\NumRows}{ % loop over rows

  % extract the data from the table
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{x}\of\mydata
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{y}\of\mydata
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{dydx}\of\mydata
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DYDX}{\pgfplotsretval}

  % calculate start and end of domain for line
  \edef\XStart{\fpeval{\X-\AxRange*0.1}}
  \edef\XEnd{\fpeval{\X+\AxRange*0.1}}
  % calculate start and end y-values of line
  \edef\YStart{\fpeval{\Y + \DYDX * (\XStart-\X)}}
  \edef\YEnd{\fpeval{\Y + \DYDX * (\XEnd-\X)}}

  % plot
  \addplot +[mark=none,thick] coordinates {(\XStart, \YStart) (\XEnd, \YEnd)};
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. One question: why is `\addplot coordinates` preferred here as opposed to the `domain` approach in the original code?

Comment: @user6593 Not sure it matters all that much, to be honest. This way that calculation is handled by `xfp` as well, though you might not see any difference in the output.

Comment: I tried replacing the `addplot` line with this `\addplot +[domain=\XStart:\XEnd,mark=none,samples=2] {\Y + \DYDX * (x-\X)};` and it gave the same result.

Comment: I am facing another issue: modifying the `y` values in the data to `2.e-6 1.e-6 3.e-6` makes all plots to start from zero. It appears that there is a lower limit that pgfplots can handle. I tried reducing the exponent from `e-0` to `e-6` and this problem showed up at `e-5`. Is there a way to handle these numbers?

Comment: @user6593 Can't say, that works fine here.